# Equivalent of C# OnDeserialized/OnSerializaed in Java?

Tags: c#, java, serialization, deserialization

Is there an equivalent to the C# [OnSerialized] and [OnDeserialized] attributes in Java?

Comment: In Java, there's not a single standard way to serialize objects, so the answer depends on how you're doing that.

Comment: @Mike that can be said of .NET too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using default Java serialization, you can override the methods used to serialize and deserialize.  These methods are:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

Just call the "default" method for each of these: out.defaultWriteObject(out) and in.defaultReadObject(in).

There's a very detailed article on Java serializtion at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: It is not very useful, because I want to add some additional logic (missed field initialization), but not override the whole thing.